# How do I construct a Joint PMF from 2 separate PMFs?

Tags: probability

I am confused on how to generate a joint pmf from two single pmfs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in general.

We need to know the relationship between the two distributions.

If you are willing to impose the assumptions that they are linearly independent, then

$$P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$$

Comment: If I were to know the relationship between the two distributions, how would I go about generating a joint pmf?

Comment: Your question is being too vague... it depends on what do you know.

Answer (score 0):

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, their marginal PMFs, respectively $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, and the PMFs of either variable conditioned on the other, respectively $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, you can obtain the joint distribution from the relation

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)=f_Y(y)f_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

Further, in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the conditional PMFs reduce to marginal PMFs so that

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=f_Y(y)f_X(x)$$